# Persisting ArcObjects workspace

Tags: arcobjects, workspace

In a custom layer I have a workspace variable (File GDB or SDE) that I need to persist (save/load).

Therefore, I need to persist the ConnectionProperties of the workspace. ConnectionProperties returns a PropertySet which implements IPersistStream so persisting this is trivial.
However, I also need to persist the type of workspace factory to use.

Unfortunately, WorkspaceFactory does not implement IPersistStream so persisting it directly does not work (returns null when reading).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The asker found a way to do this:

> Persist the WorkspaceFactory.WorkspaceType of the workspace. Then I
>   get the workspace factory with this method:
>
> ```
> public static IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory(esriWorkspaceType type)
> {
>     string stype;
>     if (type == esriWorkspaceType.esriLocalDatabaseWorkspace)
>         stype = "esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory";
>     else if (type == esriWorkspaceType.esriRemoteDatabaseWorkspace)
>          stype = "esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory";
>     else
>          return null;
>
>     Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(stype);
>     IWorkspaceFactory wsf = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
>     return wsf;
> }
> ```
>
> I don't think this is good coding practice though using hardcoded
>   strings. I would not have known these strings if I had not found them
>   in code samples from ESRI.
>
> **Is there a better way to do this?**
>
> I tried using the Type:
>
> ```
> UID uid = workspace.WorkspaceFactory.GetClassID();
> Guid guid = new Guid(uid.Value as string);
> Type workspaceFactoryType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid);
> ```
>
> This seemed more appealing since it would avoid hardcoded strings:
>
> ```
> IWorkspaceFactory wf = Activator.CreateInstance(workspaceFactoryType) as IWorkspaceFactory;
> ```
>
> The only problem is that I could not persist Type.